# Can i see class in android project which is define in flutter module

Tags: android, flutter-module

I want to define a class in flutter module and in this class there will be 2 functions.
I want to create instance for this class in android project and set settings for this class (with constructor).

And I want  call the function which is define in this class .One of them return List string , other func will be return widgert and with this I want to render widget in android with FlutterView . Is it possible ?

```
MyClass {

    typeRest string
    useDebug bool

    func Func1{
          do something with this.typeRest and this.useDebug
          and return list<String>
    }

    func Func2 {
          do something with this.typeRest and this.useDebug
          and return widget
    }


}
```

I added flutter module to android project but I can not see myclass in android project so I can not create instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have communication between the 2 sides, but generally the Flutter side does the invocation using a [MethodChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html) and you can have some java/kotlin code that responds to it. You can find tutorials online on how to do this.

If you want to send some information to the Flutter side, you have to get the Flutter/Dart code to request it instead.